# Singular Linear ODE system

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have an ODE system $Ly'= Ry$ (initial condition $y(0)=c$), where
$L=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0 &0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0 &0& -1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0 &0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0 &0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0\\
0 &0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0 &0& 0& 0& 0& 0& -1& 0\\
0 &0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0
\end{pmatrix}$
and
$R=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &0.25& 0.25& 0.25& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0.25 &-1& 0.25& 0.25& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0.25 &0.25& -1& 0.25& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0.25 &0.25& 0.25& -1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0.25 &0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0 &0.25& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0 &0& 0.25& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0 &0& 0& 0.25& 0& 0& 0& 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $y(x)$ is a vector of length 8.

That is, the matrix $L$ has a few zero rows. If it were non-singular, I would solve $(L^{-1}R)y=\lambda y$ and expand $y$ in terms of the eigenvectors $v_n$ ie $y=\sum_{n=1}^8a_ne^{\lambda_nx}v_n$ (assuming no repeated eigenvalues), and use the initial condition to find the $a_n$. Does anyone know a way to modify this procedure when $L$ is singular such as in my case?

Comment: Are $v_n$ eigenfuncions or vectors ?

Comment: vectors (edited question just now)

Comment: Let basis be ${v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6,v_7,v_8}$.The RHS does not has ${v_5,v_6,v_7,v_8}$.What does that say about LHS.